# primitive root confusion

Tags: number-theory

I found that 21 is a primitive root of 23. I wanted to find a primitive root of $529=23^2$

There is a theorem stating that if $x$ is a primitive root of $p$ and if $x^{p-1}$ is not congruent to 1 mod ($p^2)$, then $x$ is a primitive root of $p^k$.

Well $21^{22}$ is too large to work with so I reasoned that $-2$ is a primitive root mod 23. I calculated that $(-2)^{22}$ was not congruent to 1 mod 529.

This is the part I am confused about. Does this mean that $21$ is a primitive root mod 529 or that $527$ is a primitive root mod 529?

Thanks

Comment: What field are you working in? Obviously not the reals, so I presume you are working in $\mathbb Z_p$ for some $p$?

Comment: This mean that 21 is a primitive root mod 529!!

Comment: mcmat23 can you explain a bit more please

Comment: @mcmat23 can you explain a bit more please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculation that showed $(-2)^{22}\not\equiv 1\pmod{23^2}$ shows that $-2$, or equivalently $527$, is a primitive root of $23^2$.

The calculation *does not show* that $21$ is a primitive root of $23^2$, although in fact $21$ **is** a primitive root of $23^2$.

If $x\equiv 21\pmod{p}$, then $x\equiv 21+23t\pmod{23^2}$ for some $t$ in the interval $0\le t\le 22$. There is only one value of $t$ in this interval for which $21+23t$ is not a primitive root of $23^2$. (But of course $t=0$  **could** have been the bad one. It isn't, the bad one is $t=11$. )

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is a primitive root of p, then or $a$ or $p+a$ is a primitive root of $ p ^ 2$, and  this is then also a primitive root of any subsequent power of p. In fact, it is a primitive root modulo p. Then, by definition of primitive root
p-1 is the smallest exponent and divide order of $a$ . Since $a$ divide $\phi(p ^ 2)= p\cdot(p-1)$, the multiplicative order in ${Z}_{p ^ 2}^*$ , and a is a multiple p-1, and therefore can only be $(p-1)$ or the same p(p-1). In the last case, a is a primitive root of $p^2$.

Comment: I wasn't really asking why the theorem was true. Just to know the loic behind this: -2 is a primitive root of 23 and by the theorem -2 is a primitive root of 529. That is, 527 is a prim. root of 529. Where does the logic fall down here? Thanks

Comment: The theorem say that or 527 or 21 is a primitive root mod 529!There isn't a logic fall in this!

Comment: But the way I did it, I can't say that 21 is a primitive root. I can only say -2 is.

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is a prime, and $a$ is a primitive root $\pmod p$, then $a$ is a primitive root $\mod p^n$ for all integers $n$ if and only if $a^{p-1}≠1\pmod n$.